# About BinaryHeap, how to determine the initial size of array?

Tags: java, heap

```
public BinaryHeap( AnyType [ ] items ) {
    currentSize = items.length;
    array = (AnyType[]) new Comparable[ ( currentSize + 2 ) * 11 / 10 ];

    int i = 1;
    for( AnyType item : items )
        array[ i++ ] = item;
    buildHeap( );
}
```

Why is `array.length = (currentSize + 2) * 11 /10`?

Comment: Couldn't understand your question, what is `new Comparable[ ( currentSize + 2 ) * 11 / 10 ]`

Comment: I have no idea and it also seems wrong to me. Typically the array in a binary heap is allocated to be of size 2^k such that 2^k > currentSize

Comment: @KugathasanAbimaran  Anytype extends Comparable<? super AnyType> that's why I new Comparable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd interpret it like this:

- `currentSize + 2` - it is sure that two more elements will be added to the heap, increase the capacity by two
- `(currentSize + 2) * 11/10`  - increase the capacity by 10%

The thing is, such heap implementation has a limited capacity - limited by the length of the allocated array. When you insert `((currentSize + 2) * 11/10 + 1)`th element, you'll need to resize the array which might be a costly operation. Especially if you are always resizing by increasing the old array length by one.

It looks like the author of the code wanted to make sure that the size of the array will be sufficient enough to hold all the elements that might be added to it.

EDIT:

as Ivaylo Strandjev mentioned in comments, the usual way to set the heap size is to choose a `k` such that `2^k > currentSize`. The author of the code might not choose that approach if the input items size is big enough:

e.g. at most times the expected input size is ~1200 the peak is 1500, and your intial input size is 1025 elements. By the usual approach you must choose k=11 -> size is 2048 but that means that you waste (2048 - 1500 = 548) * size of AnyType object bytes in memory.